# NSFilemanager and secure delete

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfilemanager

Is there any officially supported way of secure-deleting files in Mac OS X 10.5+?

if not, what about if I move all files (using NSFilemanager) to a common folder, and use srm: from a shell script. Would this delete all traces of a file, or would the file still be recoverable because of the move operation?

thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can refer to this book, where it dose secure file wipe in objective-c http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023234.do

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: This is true, however I might be at risk if I copy and past the essential parts of the book link I have submitted since I do not have the permission of the autor of the book.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, move isn't going to copy the bytes, just change the pointers in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
NSError *err;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&err];
```

where path is a `NSString` with the path of the file you want to delete.